# Change 'title' attribute in list view in rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I use rails_admin to manage database of routers and ports. In ports index page I want to change `title` in `<td>` tag to node ip address.

This code I have in rails_admin now:

```html
<td class="node_field belongs_to_association_type" title="cisco-node-pos-156">
  <a class="pjax" href="/admin/node/85">
    cisco-node-pos-156
  </a>
</td>
```

And I want:

```html
<td class="node_field belongs_to_association_type" title="192.168.1.1">
  <a class="pjax" href="/admin/node/85">
    cisco-node-pos-156
  </a>
</td>
```

In this case `node.name = "cisco-node-pos-156"` `node.ip = "192.168.1.1"`

Illustration:
[image]

I copied index.html.haml from rails_admin source code and in this line

[%td{class: "#{property.css_class} #{property.type_css_class}", title: strip_tags(value.to_s)}= value](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/app/views/rails_admin/main/index.html.haml#L100)

I changed `strip_tags(value.to_s)` to `strip_tags(value.ip.to_s)` but error message was

> undefined method `ip' for "0":String

here "0" is the ports name.

Comment: I see you have two arrays through which you're iterating `@objects` and `properties` What kind of values are in each of these? What's an example of an object and a property?

Comment: The `object` in `@objects` is an instance of Port Class and the `property` is a column name in the ports table for example: `name`, `state` `node` etc.

Comment: Okay so you need to find out what is an instance variable of the Node class right? Because the `ip` property is on a node, correct?

Comment: Thanks for your questions. I researched a little to answer of your question and a think I found a decision. And yes, the ip property is on a node. To solve my problem I changed `strip_tags(value.to_s)` to `strip_tags(property.name.to_s == "node" ? object.node.ip : value.to_s)`. In this line condition `property.name.to_s == "node"` helps to change title to ip address only for node column. Thanks again, @Haymaker87

Answer (score 0):

I would a a custom method to your model:

```
# in your model
def title_ip
  # format stuff here
end

# in rails_admin config
list do
  include_all_fields
  field :title_ip
end
```

Or your could this in RA config

```
field :title do
  formatted_value { bindings[:object].format_stuff_here }
end
```

I would not mess with HAML files.